# from std::vector to mongo array

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

is there another way of creating a bson object from the legacy driver, mongodb that looks like:

```
{ name: "abc", vals: [0,1,2,3,...,n] }
```

with vals elements from a **std::vector of floats** ?
In the documentation i wound `BSONObjBuilder().append` is this the only way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the `BSON()` macro:

```
BSONObj b = BSON("name" << "abc" << "vals" << ba);
```

where `ba` is a `BSONArray` for the 1, 2, ..., N list. You could use `BSONArrayBuilder`to compose that array or, if you know the size of the list a priory you could use the `BSON_ARRAY()` macro:

```
BSONArray ba = BSON_ARRAY( 1 << 2 << 3 << .. N );
```